# Modifying an existing access control entry

Tags: c#, .net, windows

**I had made a logic error in the FileSystemRights interpretation which was causing it to always applied Read permission no matter what else was entered.**

I'm making a ps cmdlet which is meant to be fed a list of username and modify the permissions for a folder of the same name as the user. From my testing this script will create the new special acl entry for the user for an allow or deny entry however it will not modify the entry if it already exists. I.e. if a user has read access already and I attempt to grant write access it does not change the entry. I am not sure how I would go about modifying the existing  permission without completely removing the old permissions.

```
        DirectoryInfo diDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(FolderName);
        DirectorySecurity dsDirSecurity = diDirInfo.GetAccessControl();

       //These just interpet the objects for the rights and the allow/deny entries from the command line
        FileSystemRights FSR = genFSR();
        AccessControlType ACT = genAct();

        dsDirSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(UserName, FSR, ACT));
        diDirInfo.SetAccessControl(dsDirSecurity);
```

I tried ModifyAccessRule and got the same behavior.

```
  FileSystemAccessRule fsaRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(UserName, FSR, ACT);      
  dsDirSecurity.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Add, fsaRule, out modified);
```

Comment: how is this powershell?

Comment: Sorry if flagged wrong. I'm making a pscmdlet in c#

Comment: Is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440149/unable-to-modify-acl-perms-in-c-sharp-on-commonappdatapath-directory

Comment: Reading that it looks like it is not the same issue. The script is running as administrator and does apply the permissions the first time it is run. However if I try to change i.e. first run grant read then try to change to modify or write it does not alter them from read.

Comment: Ok. I apologize I had a typo in my FileSystemRights definition which was causing it to apply read permissions no matter what I typed. I'm sorry if this has caused any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ModifyAccessRule` instead of `AddAccessRule`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.modifyaccessrule.aspx